# How to prove to a light client that the hash of some transaction is incorrect?

Tags: merkleization

In the context of [A note on data availability and erasure coding](https://github.com/ethereum/research/wiki/A-note-on-data-availability-and-erasure-coding) and [The Data Availability Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJT_fR7wexw),
I learned that in order to scale up a coin, we need to allow light clients to join the party, and we need to teach light clients whether to trust a block or not.

In particular, if a block contains an invalid transaction, a full node can generate a fraud proof that convinces light clients not to trust this block.

But what about the following attack: A miner fakes a transaction tx1 and computes its hash value h1.  He then uses h1 along with other honest transactions' hash values to construct the Merkle tree and block, etc.  However, when he is requested to reveal the preimage of h1, he replies with tx2 which is an irrelevant but legal transaction.

Clearly the hash value of tx2 is not going to be h1, but how to prove it?
How can we convince a light client to download tx2 just to check if h1 == h(tx2)?
If we can, then what's the point of the data availability attack?

Answer (score 0):

Given tx2 you should be able to calculate hash(tx2) and if it is different from h1 you could reject the block.

Data availability affects clients that can't download the whole blockchain, for example light clients. A client that doesn't verify transaction will only download the block's header and skip the transactions. It could be attacked by a malicious miner that generates a block B with one invalid transaction tx2. That miner can generate a proof that tx2 is included in block B, since B is valid the client might incorrectly assume tx2 is valid and will accept is as a valid transaction.